# Is it needed to have unique og:description for different pages?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta

Google search engine requires pages to have different description meta tag for different pages. What is the case with open graph meta tags, mainly og:description. Is it also needed to have unique og:description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Unless you want your pages to have the same or no description on some sites that read only open graph meta tags, you have to apply different og:description to different pages. But, in terms of Google no.